# write.table in R creates txt files that it then reads incorrectly

Tags: r, list, header, write.table

So I am working in MethylKit that has a function that necessitates the use of txt files.

My original files of my data work perfectly, but due to some other issues I am troubleshooting by creating subsets of my original files.

To do so I am using:

```
write.table(head(Sample_101, n=100),"shorty_101.txt", col.names = FALSE, 
sep = "\t", row.names = TRUE)
```

I was at first running into the issue of R shifting the column names and the above line works well for fixing that issue. However, when I attempt to put the txt files into the `file.listshorty` object that will then be used for the `methRead` function, I get this:

```
file.listshorty <- list("shorty_101.txt","shorty_102.txt", "shorty_103.txt", 
                    "shorty_104.txt", "shorty_105.txt", "shorty_107.txt")


myobjS = methRead(file.listshorty, sample.id=list("Sample_101_GDM", 
"Sample_102_GDM", "Sample_103_GDM", "Sample_104_nonGDM", 
"Sample_105_nonGDM", "Sample_107_nonGDM"), assembly = "hg19", 
treatment=c(1,1,1,0,0,0), context="CpG", dbtype = "tabix", pipeline = "amp", 
header= TRUE, skip = 0, sep = "\t", resolution = "base", dbdir = getwd(), 
mincov = 10)

Error in data[, 5] * data[, 6] : non-numeric argument to binary operator
```

However when I open these txt files created by R and remove the extraneous things added to it and then read them in, it works...

To clarify --> Removed the row numbering column and the row that names the columns V1, V2, V3...V7.

```
 V1 V2 V3 V4 V5 V6 V7
1
2
3
4
5
```

I have also tried to do:

```
write.table(head(Sample_101, n=100), "shorty_101.txt", col.names = FALSE, 
sep = "\t", row.names = FALSE)
```

It gives me the same error message. I am assuming it is because the first row needs to be denoted as the header but not sure how to do this using the list function or if there is another work around.

Any help is much appreciated!

Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean "remove the extraneous things added to it "?  What extraneous things were added?

Comment: There was the row numbering and for the columns, on top of the column names there was "V1, V2, V3....V7". I removed these two things when I read the txt file in excel, and it fixed my above warning message.

Comment: Notice that your `write.table` statement says `row.names = TRUE`.  If you don't want row names, it might be better to set this to false.

Comment: I did try this, made it so both the `col.names` and `row.names` was set to false and I still get the same error message from the `methRead`.

Comment: Why are you using `sample.id=list (` instead of `sample.id=list(`. That is no space between `list` and `(`. Is that in your code or just a typo here?

Comment: Yes that is just a typo here. My code I used in R does not have this space. Will remove the spaces in my question to clarify.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out! You have to take out the quotes that are created in the txt file by adding the argument `quote = FALSE` in the `write.table` function.

```
write.table(head(Sample_101, n=100), "shorty_101.txt", col.names = FALSE, sep 
= "\t", row.names = FALSE, quote = FALSE)
```